# input a none-regular matrix in python

Tags: python, binary-tree

link: https://cw.felk.cvut.cz/courses/a4b33alg/task.php?task=pary_py&idu=2341
I want to input the matrix split by space by using:

```
def neighbour_pair(l):
    matrix = [[int(row) for row in input().split()] for i in range(l)]
```

but the program told me

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

It seems the `.split()` didn't work but I don't know why.
here is an example of the input matrix:

13 5
7 50 0 0 1
2 70 10 11 0
4 30 9 0 0
6 70 0 0 0
1 90 8 12 0
9 90 0 2 1
13 90 0 6 0
5 30 4 3 0
12 80 0 0 1
10 50 0 0 1
11 50 0 0 0
3 80 1 13 0
8 70 7 0 1
The input is a binary tree with N nodes, the nodes are labeled by numbers 1 to N in random order, each label is unique. Each node contains an integer key in the range from 0 to (2^31)−1.
The first line of input contains two integers N and R separated by space. N is the number of nodes in the tree, R is the label of the tree root.
Next, there are N lines. Each line describes one node and the order of the nodes is arbitrary. A node is specified by five integer values. The first value is the node label, the second value is the node key, the third and the fourth values represent the labels of the left and right child respectively, and the fifth value represents the node color, white is 0, black is 1. If any of the children does not exist there is value 0 instead of the child label at the corresponding place. The values on the line are separated by a space.

Comment: can you provide an example of your input and also your `l` variable?

Comment: input is the matrix inside the link,down below,example 1,I don't know why I can't just copy and paste in here.
and "l" is all the matrix

Comment: Please update your post to follow the interactive console workflow.  Do you assign `l` first? Do you execute the `matrix = ...` line first followed by inputing the input values as a string?  Demonstrate exactly what you are doing, step-by-step that leads you to the error message

Answer (score 1):

This is the `range()` complaining that your `l` variable is a string:

```
>>> range('1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I suspect you are reading the `l` from the standard in as well, cast it to integer:

```
l = int(input())
matrix = [[int(row) for row in input().split()] for i in range(l)]
```

Comment: What are you using as your input to test?

Comment: @sadmicrowave well if I use `3` and then input 3 space-separated rows, it works (no errors). If I remove the `int()` when defining `l`, it will fail exactly as in OP's case. Pretty sure this is it.

Comment: gotcha, yes.  I follow that logic; I'm going to post something similar to demonstrate what the input flow looks line in a  console window

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @alecxe.  It seems that your error is in reference to the string being used as `l` in your `range(l)` function.  If I put a static `int` in the `range()` function it seems to work.  `3` followed by three rows of input, will give me the below output.

```
>>> l = input() # define the number of rows expected the input matrix
>>> [[int(row) for row in input().split()] for i in range(int(l))]
13 5
7 50 0 0 1
2 70 10 11 0
```

output

```
[[13, 5], [7, 50, 0, 0, 1], [2, 70, 10, 11, 0]]
```

Implemented as a method, per the OP request in the comments below:

```
def neighbour_pair():
    l = input()
    return [[int(row) for row in input().split()] for i in range(int(l))]

print( neighbour_pair() )
# input
   # 3
   # 13 5
   # 7 50 0 0 1
   # 2 70 10 11 0
# output
[[13, 5], [7, 50, 0, 0, 1], [2, 70, 10, 11, 0]]
```

Still nothing wrong with this implementation...

Comment: ehh,I'm using your corrected code to test but from the second row the code seems not working  

 `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7 50 0 0 1'`

Comment: it's like the first row with 2 value is okay,but something wrong from second row that contains 5 value

Comment: I'm not getting an error, what are you defining as `l`? Also, what version of python are you using?

Comment: python3.5 .
`l` is the whole input matrix like `'13 5'
'7 50 0 0 1'
'2 70 10 11 0'`

Comment: I fixed it, in python3+ you don't need quotes around the input strings.  This actually causes the values to be double quoted and resolves to `"'13 5'"`... So the split was making the array resolve to `["'13", "5'"]`

Comment: Is it possible that you show me a fixed code from `def xxxx(input)` to `return` that output is the matrix in `[[13, 5], [7, 50, 0, 0, 1], [2, 70, 10, 11, 0]]` this form? cause I still don't know what's wrong with the `int()`,there's no other things..

Comment: Is there anything else you can tell me about how you are conducting your test?  perhaps upload a screenshot of your console including your function line, input, and error?

Comment: ^ if you are getting an error on the list comprehension line, then wrapping it in a `def` method isn't going to help anything.  Let's figure out why you are getting an error first, then you can wrap it in methods and classes until your heart is content

Comment: `def neighbour_pair(l):`
    `l = input()`
    `matrix = [[int(row) for row in input().split()] for i in range(int(l))]`
    `return matrix`
`if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(neighbour_pair(input()))`
Then input:
`13 5`
`7 50 0 0 1`
`2 70 10 11 0`
Program shows:
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7 50 0 0 1'`
sorry I'm still not fimilar of the format,hope it's readable

Comment: check my post again, still not getting an error and doing the same thing you are doing... by the way, if you are expressing `l = input()` within your def, then you don't need to pass it in as an argument and define it in `__main__` that is redundant